# Spark encode in Gzip and send to S3 - java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, gzip

I'm trying to GZIP and send an RDD over to S3 like so:

```
dwPartitioned.saveAsTextFile(s"s3n://$accessKey:$secretKey@bucket", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

The job starts running and shortly after comes up with:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:  ... : java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

I read that because of the encoding there is some shuffling done which requires temporary files to be generated. Is that true? Am I misusing the functionality? Is there something that I can optimize here?

More importantly - how can I achieve this in memory?

If you need more info I'll gladly append it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, spark uses "`/tmp`" to save intermediate files. When the job is running, you can tab "`df -h`" to see the used space of fs mounted at "/" growing up. When the space of the dev is runned out of, this exception is throwed. To solve the problem, set the SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in the `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark_defaults.conf` with a path in a `fs` leaving enough space.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working in a Notebook in Databricks and they don't allow you to manage your clusters. So not much I can do about that.